# Quantum Hardware For Silq

Tags: quantum-computing

Does Silq gives access to quantum computers and simulators? In the way that [Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/) and [Amazon Braket](https://aws.amazon.com/braket/) provide access to real quantum computers.

Comment: By silq I mean https://silq.ethz.ch/